# Brivis Wombat Classic startup behaviour

Tags: hvac, furnace, gas, blower

I have a Brivis Classic 2P Wombat 26 gas furnace in a place we moved into late last year. We didn't really experience winter then so hadn't had much of a chance to use the ducted heating much.

Now with the cold weather coming around, I started to pay close attention to the behaviour of the system. And something about it's startup seems odd.

When the thermostat sends its signal to turn on the flame, it starts its ignition sequence to light the pilot flame then lights the burners. But immediately as that happens there is an audible click (likely the gas valve clicking off) and the burner turn off and the blower kicks in. Seconds later, as the fan is already running, the ignition recommences and the burner once again is lit. This time it stays on. Then the system functions as normal.

Normal operation according to the manual is that the blower starts 45secs after the main burners are ignited.

This behaviour is not consistent either. So once the heating is going, then turns off as it reaches the desired temp, then later gets a signal to turn back on, the ignition process is as normal (blower starting 45secs later). But if I were to leave the furnace off for a while, and turn it back on later in the day, the the initial ignition experiences the strange behaviour.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? At times it doesn't seem to be a big issue, apart from cold air blowing out first until it eventually heats up. But occasionally their will also be a mini 'explosion' from the burners due to the delayed reignition. Perhaps because some gas from the first try is still present? This is what I'm concerned about.

Some photos of the system:

[image]

[image]

[image: I have sourced a spare part image the pilot assembly]

I have sourced a spare part image the pilot assembly

Comment: Does the system have a control board, or just a standing pilot + a gas control thermocouple?

Comment: Yes it has a control board. I have edited my post to include some photos of the system if it helps.

Comment: "Classic Wombat startup" with a title like that I didn't know what to expect, but I expected it to be good! :D

Comment: I have since tried cleaning the flame sensor as I have seen suggested in numerous places. It seemed to work correctly the first time I reinstalled it. After that, the same issue persists...

Can the cold weather be affecting the flame sensor? My cleaning would have 'warmed' it up I imagine, which is why it worked as normal the first time around.